# Can I switch of screen of my windows 8.1 laptop while programs running in the background

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display

I have a laptop with windows 8.1 64 bit OS.

Can I switch off my laptop screen and run my (python) programs in the background?
This will cause my laptop to save battery power.
When any key is pressed, laptop should switch on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the power plan settings in Windows so the lid switch does nothing, then close the lid.

To do this, under `Choose what closing the lid does`, select `Do nothing` for `When I close the lid` option.